# C#: No overload for 'function' matches delegate System.Threading.WaitCallBack

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, overloading, threadpool

So I've been using threads lately and the error (C#: No overload for 'Generic_Function' matches delegate System.Threading.WaitCallBack) is confusing me a bit.

At first I thought there had to be a parameter passed, then I learned it could easily be null.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Generic_Function), null);
```

Shouldn't be the function then defined as:

```
void Generic_Function(){
 //Code here
}
```

However, I'm getting an error. I'm missing something here and I'm boggled. I've tried reading the docs but I guess I'm not grasping this fully. I'd appreciate if someone could explain. Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waitcallback?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), a WaitCallback is defined like this:

```
public delegate void WaitCallback(object state);
```

So you can make this modification if you'd like your code to work:

```
void Generic_Function(object state)
{
    //Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reasons you can't change `Generic_Function` signature you can wrap a call with lambda:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => Generic_Function());
```